# Jquery datepicker: disable click on date

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I'm using JQuery Datepicker and I only want the datepicker being hidden, when click on "Done" button.
So when clicking on a date, it selects it, but you have to confirm with "Done".

I'd like to send my form to a javascript function when the user clicks on "Done" also.

Here is my code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery('#datepickers').datepicker({
      showButtonPanel: true,
      firstDay: 1,
      minDate: 0,
      maxDate: "+1m",
      dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
      closeText: "Search",
      onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
               //Disable this.
      }
    });

})
```

Comment: use the inline approach  http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#inline

Comment: I do not use an input. I only want it to appear when clicking on a div and then confirm date with done.

Comment: create a demo in jsfiddle.net , should be simple to hide/show it

Comment: It is, but can't insert a button in inline datepicker to send the form

Comment: no, probably not (without refactoring plugin source) but why does button need to be in the datepicker itself?

Comment: Maybe: Jquery.('#datepickers').hide(); yourFunction(dateText);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank to charlietfl,

Inline approach was the way to proceed.

But you can't add a Done button on the buttonpane.
So I added a button, with the same theme css and it solved it.

Answer (score 0):

I have One Solution May be it will be useful for someone

```
$(".selectorpath").click(function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
        $(this).attr("href","javascript:void(0)");
});
```